# How do I say that an investment program is set to last until 2025?

Tags: phrase-request, translation

I have a sentence in Russian:

> Компания в рамках **инвестиционной программы до 2025 года** продолжает дальнейшее наращивание мощностей и объемов производства.

My translation:

> The company is proceeding with expansion of its production capacity and output in line with its **investment program which is set to last until 2025**.

In Russian, the phrase goes: "its **investment program until 2025**" - the phrase is short and clear - the program foresees steps to be taken until 2025.

In English, I have to write "which is set to last until", which is a mouthful. Can I simply say "investment program until 2025" to make it shorter? Is there some other way to make this phrase short?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> investment program until 2025

would be understood, but this version is clearer:

> investment program *running* until 2025

would sound natural.

---

Relevant dictionary entry:

> 16. to continue in force
>       The exhibit *runs* until the end of the month.

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run))</sub>

Comment: +1, or *...program, which runs until 2025*.